# Specify colors for individual style tags

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

Is it possible to specify colorPrimary and colorAccent for individual style elments rather than in theme tag

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="android:Widget">        
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray900</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/gray50</item>

    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabLayout2" parent="android:Widget">        
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray50</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/gray900</item>

    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

When I try doing this the default theme is applied. Is there a way/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Widgets look up their accent colors etc on the context theme. You can define different themes to hold your styles, and apply them to different layouts using `android:theme` attribute, if you use the latest appcompat suport library. See https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Citing an example there:

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<style name="RedThemeOverlay" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material">
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

**res/layout/fragment_list.xml**

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:theme="RedThemeOverlay" />
```